# Foursquare/Fandango Integration

Tags: api, foursquare

I would like to know more about the Foursquare/Fandango integration. Specifically where do Fandango ID's come from?

In [the documentation for Events](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/event), there is a field called `foreignIds` that describes itself as:

> The count of ids of this event in third-party services, plus items, an array of domain, the third party provider, and id, the id in their system.

For instance, here is part of a response for Fast & Furious 6:

```
{
  venueId: "45b893e3f964a520cf411fe3"
  id: "517d89675df9910ab5fb61bb"
  name: "Fast & Furious 6"
  foreignIds: {
    count: 1
    items: [
      {
        domain: "fandango.com"
        id: "6011-155438"
      }
    ]
}
```

My question is: where does the identifier `6011-155438` come from? Can it be referenced by some API somewhere (either on Foursquare's side or Fandango's side)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the "6011-" part of the ID, but 155438 appears to be Fandango's identifier for "Fast and the Furious 6" in their RSS feed for the movie (http://www.fandango.com/rss/fast26furious6/155438.rss) and in the URL for the movie itself (http://www.fandango.com/fast26furious6_155438/movieoverview).

I don't know how you'd generate/guess the "fast26furious6" string to generate those URLs from a Foursquare/Fandango ID, though, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Anyone else have any ideas? Fandango doesn't seem to offer any sort of API other than these RSS feeds: http://www.fandango.com/rss/moviefeed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this up! It turns out this isn't a very useful thing to include in our API response because, as you have noted, there's really no practical application of this ID. We'll remove it from future versions of the API.

Comment: Will there be any sort of unique identifier for movies going forward then? Some sort of consistency would be nice, maybe like IMDB IDs or TMS or something?

Comment: Nothing to announce right now, but I'll bring this up to our internal teams as feedback. It's going to be a bit janky, but for now, if you need to cross-reference entities across Foursquare and some movie database, I would just use a simple string matching technique and take your best guess based on the fact that most events returned by our API will be recent movies.